# How to get a String value of resources folder (Java)

Tags: java, string, resources

I'm a beginner in programming and I have a class that requires a path to some folder in its constructor. For example:

```
 SomeClass class = new SomeClass(c:/folder);
```

I need to get a `String` value of `resources` folder (only path to folder without specific file names). A method in that class will add a filename to path from constructor and do some operations with a specific file.

I'm trying to do this (bad code!), but just have `npe`:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("src/main/resources").getFile());
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

So, the question is: how to get `String` value of `resources` folder?

Comment: What is the filename you are searching for? Your path should lead to that one and you do not need to include the resources path

Comment: *"src/main/resources"* This is the wrong way to do it. At runtime you don't have this path. Your IDE is copying the content of `src/main/resources` to `target` or `bin` where you can access the copies via `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),"your file name")`.

Comment: Do not under any circumstances convert a URL to a file using the getFile() method.  That method *does not* convert the URL to a valid file name.  It merely returns the path portion of the URL, which may contain percent-escapes for the many characters which are not permitted in URLs.  A resource cannot be referred to using java.io.File.  Read the URL as a URL, not as a File.  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=201701111734535687024&a=remarks .

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem:

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

So, I got `String` path to `resources` folder.